# Playing audio from an internal location on iPhone

Tags: html, ios

I have a simple site which I want to play audio on iPhone safari. It has **only** the following code:

```
   <audio style="height:77px;" controls>
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>
```

Note the src is local. This does **not** play the audio

However if I change the source to something external such as this...

```
   <audio style="height:77px;" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>
```

It works perfectly.

It's worth pointing out both methods work fine on desktop, on iPhone only the external src works.

Any ideas for why this may be happening?

Comment: On iPhone Safari browser?

Comment: because "horse.mp3" file not present in application directory.
Every application have it's own local directory.

Comment: Yes, also the same for Chrome on iPhone

Comment: @VineetChoudhary It is in the local directory, it's just not playing

Comment: it is in iOS simulator application local directory ??

Comment: @VineetChoudhary This isn't an application it's just a normal website. The audio is in the root folder of the website and works on desktop

Comment: @CraigPowell Try this "~/horse.mp3" or "/horse.mp3"

Comment: @VineetChoudhary This didn't work either